# How can I use haml to set an inline style for my ruby on rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am trying to build a form using ruby on rails with formtastic and haml.  Everything works except I am not able to set an inline style on my input field.  I would like to grey out a text box when it has been set to read-only.  I am successfully able to set the field to be read-only, but the style tag is not working.  It literally does not show up in the code when viewed on the demo site.

How can I set an inline style using haml?

```
= semantic_form_for @article do |f|
  = f.inputs do
    = f.input :id, "style" => "background-color:#000000", input_html: { readonly: true }
```

The code that isn't working at all is:

```
"style" => "background-color:#000000",
```

I've been looking here: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#htmlstyle_attributes_

But I haven't been able to figure it out.  Im still a newbie!  Can you help?

Comment: Note that I did try to use the following phrasing ---> "style" => "background-color:#000000"  || with no different results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `style` is an html option, add it to `input_html` hash.  Also, make sure that style's attribute, value pair is closed by a semi-colon:

```
= f.input :id, input_html: { style: 'background-color: #000000;', readonly: true }
```